# One to many relation: group by column on the many side and count the rows in the one side

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count, query-optimization

I have two tables say A and B, one to many relations (B has foreign key to A). Now I have a requirement to group by a column in B, but count the number of rows in A ( distinct). Is that possible to do without using COUNT (distinct A.Id)

```
   SELECT b.column1,
         Count(*) totalGroupCount,
         Count(distinct a.id) CountOfA   -- I dont want to this for perf reason
   FROM A a JOIN B b on a.id = b.a_id
   GROUP BY b.column1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count distinct values, then `count(distinct ...)` is the way to go. A workaround will probably not perform faster.

Let me suggest, however, to simplify your query: you don't need table `a` to get the result you want (especially if you have a foreign key constraint). This is good enough:

```
select column1, count(*) totalgroupcount, count(distinct a_id)
from b
group by column1
```

Then, you might try an index on `b(column1, a_id)` for performance.